# Lambda function to delete an S3 bucket using Boto

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am working on a Boto script to delete the resource when invoked by a lambda function, I am not sure how to invoke the delete function using Lambda, `"path"` has the resource to be deleted and below is the lambda function being used to delete the resource . Thanks in advance.

```
print(path)
def delete_bucket(path):  
    while True:
        objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=path)
        content = objects.get('Contents', [])
        if len(content) == 0:
            break
        for obj in content:
            s3.delete_object(Bucket=path, Key=obj['Key'])
    s3.delete_bucket(Bucket=path)
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    delete_bucket(path)
```

Comment: Why are you even using a Lambda function if you don't know how it's going to be invoked? Are you sure writing this code in Lambda is the right place for it to run? What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 3):

Following code is verified on Python 3.8;

```
import boto3


def get_s3_client():
    return boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-1') #change region_name as per your setup

def delete_bucket(bucket_name): #here bucket_name can be path as per logic in your code 
    s3_client = get_s3_client()
    while True:
        objects = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)
        content = objects.get('Contents', [])
        if len(content) == 0:
            break
        for obj in content:
            s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=obj['Key'])
    s3_client.delete_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # put your existing logic here
    delete_bucket(path)
```

*Note*: If you have versioning enabled for the bucket, then you will need extra logic to list objects using `list_object_versions` and then iterate over such a version object to delete them using `delete_object`

Comment: I have made changes to the question according to your answer but it still does not delete the S3 Bucket. Could you please take a look and tell me what might be wrong with the syntax.I had already declared the S3 client beforehand so deleted that line from your code.TIA.

Comment: I don't have versioning enabled